# How install Wordpress in a EC2 machine?

Tags: apache, tomcat, wordpress

I have an `EC2` instance running with `Glassfish Server Open Source Edition`.
And now I need to setup the a website in wordpress.

How can I do that ?

I'm looking for [5 minutes installation tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) but I'm stuck in the part where it's says about the webserver.
I have to install the Apache in Linux then enable the FTP access ? (to upload the wordpress files ? )

For now I'm stuck in this part guys, any tip is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is going to be a bit of a high level overview of what you need to do. Its a long process which you need to look into.

Glassfish server is (afaik) for Java applications. Wordpress is a PHP/mysql based system.

Apache is a free and open source web server which you can use, which integrates with php and mysql nicely. What you need is called a LAMP setup (LAMP stands for "linux, apache, mysql and php). You haven't specified what your EC2 is running (what linux distro) but lets say its Ubuntu. A quick search for "installing lamp ubuntu" on google turns up many different tutorials and walkthroughs for installing a lamp setup on your machine.

You'll need SSH access (which you'll have with EC2) then if you run through your tutorial of choice you'll have a working web server, you'll specify a `public_html` directory (usually by default `/var/www`).

Now to install Wordpress. What you could do is install an FTP server. This is going to be relatively complicated though, however it will be the easiest way to install Wordpress. Install FTP and upload the wordpress files to the public html directory, then you will be able to run through the 5 minute install process using the mysql database credentials you set up in the LAMP tutorial.

An easier way to do what you need to do is to install subversion on your EC2 instance - e.g. `sudo apt-get install subversion` on ubuntu. That way you can `svn export` the wordpress repository to your public html folder (http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing/Updating_WordPress_with_Subversion).

However, without an FTP server running on your EC2 instance you won't be able to FTP in to modify files or anything. You'll have to do everything over SSH (or SFTP) which may or may not be manageable for you.

In all honesty, and with the utmost respect, if you don't know about apache and installing a LAMP server and such then you're probably a bit out of your depth with Amazon's EC2 server. You'd be better off with a dedicated server from a hosting company who will have installed everything you need.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Clayson, I already had one account in Wordpress, I'm trying to learn about more wordpress, thanks by your tip.

Comment: I'm not sure I would install an FTP server? One could use `sshfs` and thus mount the remote server's `public_html` dir as a local directory. That's easier than FTP I think

Comment: I don't know much about sshfs. I've always managed to work with ftp servers and such.